# Centering a tikz-cd diagram without ampersand replacement

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-cd

I have a tikz-cd diagram that is a bit too wide for the page.  By default, when placed in a displaymath environment, it spills over into the right-hand margin.  I would like it instead to be centered on the page, spilling over into both margins (half as much each).  The best way I know of to do this is by putting the whole diagram in a mathclap.  But this clobbers the ampersand, requiring tikz-cd to be given `ampersand replacement` and written using something other than an ordinary `&`.  How can I write an ordinary tikz-cd diagram and center it on the page without going through and replacing all the `&`s with `\&` (or whatever)?

Here is a MWE that produces the result I want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\[
\mathclap{\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
  \text{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} \ar[r] \&
  \text{consectetur adipiscing elit} \ar[r] \&
  \text{sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt}
\end{tikzcd}}
\]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is the sort of thing I'd like to be able to write instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\begin{centeredtikzcd}
  \text{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} \ar[r] &
  \text{consectetur adipiscing elit} \ar[r] &
  \text{sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt}
\end{centeredtikzcd}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your own environment using `lrbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newenvironment{forcedcentertikzcd}
 {\begin{lrbox}{\forcedcentertikzcdbox}\begin{tikzcd}}
 {\end{tikzcd}\end{lrbox}\makebox[0pt]{\usebox{\forcedcentertikzcdbox}}}
\newsavebox{\forcedcentertikzcdbox}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\[
\begin{forcedcentertikzcd}
  \text{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} \ar[r] &
  \text{consectetur adipiscing elit} \ar[r] &
  \text{sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt}
\end{forcedcentertikzcd}
\]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\[
\hspace{-.2\textwidth}\begin{tikzcd}
  \text{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} \ar[r] &
  \text{consectetur adipiscing elit} \ar[r] &
  \text{sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt}
\end{tikzcd}\hspace{-.2\textwidth}
\]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You left the ampersand replacement in, but this works without it too.  However, why does it clobber the vertical space around the display?

Comment: @MikeShulman sorry fixed both (there was no need to add so much negative space that the total width of the expression is negative )